# Not able to read elements of array of pointer expcept of 0th element

Tags: c, arrays

i have a array and want to pass it to a function which wants array of pointer as an argument when i pass it with the reference it only gives me the first element of that array. What am i doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc{
    int a;
};

void a(struct abc* j[]){
    printf("%d\n",j[1]->a);
}

int main()
{
    struct abc* k = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct abc));
    k[0].a = 2;
    k[1].a = 3;
    a(&k);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanx, this works, can u explain me why j[1]->a doesnt?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks buddy that explains well!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks buddy, i got it, can u make it an answer so it may be easier for others to find the solution, if somebody has problem i had

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf("%d\n",j[1]->a);` should be `printf("%d\n",(*j)[1].a);`

`(*j)[1].a)` means `k[1].a`. (`j = &k`, `(*j)[1].a)` ==> `(*&k)[1].a` ==> `(k)[1].a`)

note : `*j[1]` means `*(j[1])`. So `*j` must be enclosed in parentheses(like as `(*j)`).

`struct abc* j[]` means array of pointer to `struct abc`.

case of function call as `a(&k);`
`j` is equivalent to an array with only one `k`. (like as `struct abc* j[] = { k };`)
So `j[1]` is the fact that an invalid pointer.

`j[0]` means the `k`So the following is valid.

```
printf("%d\n", j[0]->a);//2
printf("%d\n", (j[0]+1)->a);//3
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: You are currently not creating an array of pointers.  You currently are creating an array of structs.  To create an array of pointers, do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc{
    int a;
};

void a(struct abc* j[]){
    printf("%d\n",j[1]->a);
}

int main()
{
    struct abc **k = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct abc *));

    k[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    k[1] = malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    k[0]->a = 2;
    k[1]->a = 3;
    a(k);
    return 0;
}
```

Old: If you want to do it with just an array of structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc{
    int a;
};

void a(struct abc* j){
    printf("%d\n",j[1].a);
}

int main()
{
    struct abc* k = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct abc));
    k[0].a = 2;
    k[1].a = 3;
    a(k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i want array of pointers as argument of the function. Thanks for ur time

Comment: @user3734435 But you don't have an array of pointers.  You have an array of structs.  If you want to pass an array of pointers, then you need to first create an array of pointers.

Comment: what if i have a function void a(sturct abc* j[]) or void a(struct abc** j) and i want pass struct abc* k to the function? Thank u

Comment: its a great answer but i dont want to create array of pointers first, i just want a array and then pass it to a function which has array of pointers as argument, like `struct a* b; //an array` and `void d(struct a** b);` and pass `struct a* b` to `void d(struct a** b);`, the one from @BLUEPIXY in comments works but i dont understand why? Thanks for u time mate!

Comment: @user3734435 What you are saying doesn't make sense.  It's like you are saying I have a function that takes a banana as an argument but I want to pass an apple to it, how can I do that?  You can't.  The comment by BLUEPIXY treated your array of pointers as an array of structs so it really didn't use the array as an array of pointers.

Comment: i understand it now, was confused. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the array. Pass the pointer the first element and the number of elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc{
    int a;
};

void a(struct abc* j, int num){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
       printf("element %d has a value %d\n", i, j[i].a);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct abc* k = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct abc));
    k[0].a = 2;
    k[1].a = 3;
    a(k, 2);
    free(k);
    return 0;
}
```

If an array of pointers is what you're after do it like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc{
    int a;
};

void a(struct abc** j){
    struct abc** tmp = j;

    while(*tmp != NULL)
    {
       printf("value is %d\n", (*tmp)->a);
       tmp++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct abc** k = malloc(3 * sizeof(struct abc*));
    k[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    k[0]->a = 3;
    k[1] = malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    k[1]->a = 2;
    k[2] = NULL;
    a(k);

    free(k[0]);
    free(k[1]);
    free(k);
    return 0;
}
```